# I need error handling with XML variable lookup when our website is down or the client PC does not have Internet access

Tags: vba, vb.net

I need some way to ignore The following call out when the user does not have internet access or our website is down.

```
Dim RemoteURL = "https://sample.com/InfoApp/notify.xml"
        Dim X = XDocument.Load(RemoteURL)
```

How can I have this section skip so error mess of continue or quit does not show up?

```
        Dim RegID = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyAPP", "ID", Nothing)
        Dim RemoteURL = "https://sample.com/InfoApp/notify.xml"
        Dim X = XDocument.Load(RemoteURL)
        Dim ID = X.<notify>.<ID>.Value
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyAPP", "ID", ID)
        Alert.Show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032162/excel-vba-abort-script-if-network-connection-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this to check if there is a connection:

```
Function CheckInternet() As Boolean
Dim req As Object
Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
req.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com", False
req.Send
If req.Status <> 200 Then
    CheckInternet = False
Else
    CheckInternet = True
End If
End Function
```

It will create a request to google in this case. If the status is 200, everything is ok. Otherwise chance is high that there is no connection, or that google.com is offline. You can also fill in your own URL here of course.